# European aircraft liveries list

Tags: eu, livery

We live few miles away of an airport and we see a lot of departures and I would like a tool to enable my 7 year old daughter to recognize the company from the livery.

Is there a pdf or anything else (printable) with the list of the main airlines that fly in Europe with their liveries?

The best would be with some pictures (or even drawings) of their most common aircraft seen by different angles.

We live in northern Italy by the way (near MXP/LIMC) if there is a list for those who fly in Italy.

Comment: I just want to say that I think this is a lovely idea. My 3-year old daughter frequently asks me to open my flight-radar app to check where an aircraft is coming from/going to, so I can very much relate to this. Be careful though, I got my first aircraft book (including a chapter full of pictures of liveries of airlines from around the world) when I was 8 years old and I have been hooked to aviation since :-). Over time it got so bad that I even ended up moderating this site!

Answer (score 7):

This is really a three part question, I'll try to answer it appropriately

**What airlines fly into Milan Malpensa airport (MXP/LIMC)**

The first place I'd start is the [arrival](https://www.milanomalpensa-airport.com/en/flights/arrivals) and [departure](https://www.milanomalpensa-airport.com/en/flights/departures) info for the airport itself. A quick glance shows the usual european low-cost operators (EasyJet, Wizz & Ryanair) as well as the larger operators (Emirates, British Airways, American, Singapore, Air China, Lufthansa, Cathay Pacific and of course, Alitalia!).

You can also check out the airport's wiki page which has a helpful section on [Airlines and destinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milan_Malpensa_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations) served by the airport (direct link).

**What do the liveries of specific airlines look like**

I'm not sure you'll find a single handy pdf with all these on, but again wikipedia has some helpful information - indeed a specific list of [airline liveries and logos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_liveries_and_logos). Cross reference this list with the one above and you could pull together a helpful cheat-sheet of all the ones which fly into LIMC.

**How do I identify different types of airliner**

Thankfully, the list of commonly used airframes is reasonably small, unfortunately with quite a fair number of variants of the same model if you're trying to be exact.

Once again, wikipedia will give you information about each of your chosen airline's fleet, and you can check arrivals and departures on something like [flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/MXP) to see which aircraft are flying which route.

There are websites dedicated to the art of identifying commercial airliners such as [airlinespotter.com](https://www.airlinerspotter.com/how-to-identify-commercial-airliners.htm) and [aircraftrecognitionguide.com](https://www.aircraftrecognitionguide.com/).